# Create Report with Camel

Tags: apache-camel, report

I would like to ask if there is a module for Apache Camel that I can use in order to build a report and exported afterwards to PDF.

Report will have some text and also a bar-code.

Is this something that can be done via Camel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apache Camel has a [PDF component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-pdf/src/main/docs/pdf-component.adoc) and a [BarCode component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-barcode/src/main/docs/barcode-dataformat.adoc). PDF Component uses [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and the BarCode component uses [ZXIng](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) under the hood. Both are powerful libraries and may work(or not) based on how complicated your requirements are. Some level of plumbing involved as always :)

Comment: Hello, I am already aware of those 2 components and I am able to produce PDFs and Barcodes, but separately. What I would like to achieve is to create a Report that it will have some information and a Barcode. Do you know if this is possible with these 2 components? Or if there is another one?

Comment: In my use cases which were rather complex, I wrote a custom processor with iText and Zxing. I haven't used these components together. Perhaps someone who used them together would help.